# Jinja won't print out object or iterate through list

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So, i'm passing my json object through render_template (flask) into my .html page and using jinja with the following code, I want to create table rows in my table:

```
{% if showData %}

            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">Performer Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Twitter Handle</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>{{showData}}
                {% for performer in showData.performers %}
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">1</th>
                      <td>{{performer}}</td>
                      <td>@mdo</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>        
        {% endif %}
```

If I print out the object 'showData' (as you can see done in the code with {{showData}}), it will print out the entire json, which looks like this:

```
[{u'category': u'Comedy', u'rating': 5, u'name': u'first show', u'img': u'firstshow.jpg', u'performers': [u'Bob bob', u'Alex alex', u'James james'], u'url': u'first_show', u'venue': 2, u'viewTimes': [u'12:00', u'14:00', u'16:00'], u'description': u'blah blah blah'}]
```

But if I try loop through showData.performers, it doesn't show up with anything. Even if I try to print out showData.name, it's empty

Any ideas why? Cheers

Comment: `showData` looks like an array, containing a dict. Shouldn't your for loop therefore be `for performer in showData[0].performers`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you :)